# Paypal Adaptive Payments works in sandbox mode but not production

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-adaptive-payments

I'm trying to use Paypal's adaptive payments API and having a tough time switching it to production. Everything works as expected on sandbox mode and I get a proper response, but when I switch to my live APP ID it doesn't work.

These are the configuration values I'm using for sandbox

```
PayPal URL : https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/webapps/adaptivepayment/flow/pay?paykey=[TOKEN_HERE]
Application ID : APP-80W284485P519543T
```

These values work for me in sandbox mode. But when I switch to the below production values, it stops working

```
PayPal URL : https://www.paypal.com/webapps/adaptivepayment/flow/pay?paykey=[TOKEN_HERE]
Application ID : [ACTUAL APP ID]

This is what I mean by stops working.
```

- In production mode, the application gets the paykey
- Appends it to the Paypal URL and then redirects it to their site
- On site load, I get the following message

```
This transaction has already been approved. Please visit your PayPal Account Overview to see the details
```

The final URL it ends up on - `https://ic.paypal.com/webapps/adaptivepayment/flow/payinit?execution=e6s1`

Screenshot - http://screencast.com/t/28qJZ9CIk

There is also a 'Return' button there, and when I click on it I get taken to a different site each time (Looks like I get sent to random failUrls)

I've included the code I use below

```
$payRequest = new PayRequest();
$payRequest->actionType     = "PAY";
$payRequest->cancelUrl      = $cancelURL; //my success and fail urls
$payRequest->returnUrl      = $returnURL;

$payRequest->clientDetails  = new ClientDetailsType();
$payRequest->clientDetails->applicationId   = $this->config['application_id'];
$payRequest->clientDetails->deviceId        = $this->config['device_id'];
$payRequest->clientDetails->ipAddress       = $this->CI->input->ip_address();

$payRequest->currencyCode = $currencyCode;

$payRequest->requestEnvelope = new RequestEnvelope();
$payRequest->requestEnvelope->errorLanguage = "en_US";

//I set the receiver and the amounts. I also define that these are digital goods payments       
$receiver1 = new receiver();
$receiver1->email   = $opts['receiver_email'];
$receiver1->amount  = $opts['amount'];
$receiver1->paymentType = 'DIGITALGOODS';
$payRequest->receiverList = new ReceiverList();
$payRequest->receiverList = array($receiver1);

//Then I make the call
$ap          = new AdaptivePayments();
$response    = $ap->Pay($payRequest);

if(strtoupper($ap->isSuccess) == 'FAILURE') {
    log_message('error', "PAYMENT_FAIL : " . print_r($ap->getLastError(), true));
    return false;
} else {
    if($response->paymentExecStatus == "COMPLETED")  {
        header("Location: " . $this->config['success_url']);
        exit;
    } else {
        $token      = $response->payKey;
        $payPalURL  = $this->config['paypal_redirect_url'] . 'paykey='.$token;
        header("Location: ".$payPalURL);
        exit;
    }
}
```

This is code taken from their sample implementation, so not really sure what's going wrong here. Other information that might be relevant

- I'm using adaptive payments to make sure that the sender and receiver
  actually did the transaction
- I have set the payment type as 'DIGITAL GOODS'

**EDIT**

I've included a sample URL with the pay key attached

```
https://www.paypal.com/webapps/adaptivepayment/flow/pay?paykey=AP-0H388650F08226841
```

Comment: Can you include an echo of $payPalURL?

Comment: @Robert sure, I've updated the question with that info.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the issue that was giving me all of this grief.

The Paypal SDK uses a couple of constants which are defined in `/sdk/lib/Config/paypal_sdk_clientproperties`

The constants contain the username, password, application_id the API url and a few others. These are used directly in the file `/sdk/lib/CallerServices,php`. So contrary to what you would expect in an API, these values are not injected in the setup phase so if you don't notice that file and change the values, the above code will not work.

To fix the issue, simply update the values defined in the file and you should be good to go.